# Rails order a collection of column_names

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using `column_names` from a Rails table in a form.

column_names() public
Returns an array of column names as strings.

How do I order the collection list?

This doesn't work:

```
<%= f.input :field_name, :label => "Field Name", :collection => Vehicle.column_names.order(:name) %>
```

I get:

```
undefined method `order' for #<Array
```

This doesn't work either:

```
<%= f.input :field_name, :label => "Field Name", :collection => Vehicle.column_names.sort_by{|e| e[:name]} %>
```

I get:

```
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

Comment: Are you just trying to order the column names alphabetically? `Vehicle.column_names.sort` should work for that purpose.

Comment: Zajn - please submit as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Looks like AnkitG has that covered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Model.column_names** returns a array of column names.

**Eg below**

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.13)
#Customer is my rails model
2.1.2 :001 > Customer.column_names
 => ["id", "customer_name", "customer_tier", "customer_channel", "created_at", "updated_at"] 

#this sorts it
2.1.2 :002 > Customer.column_names.sort
 => ["created_at", "customer_channel", "customer_name", "customer_tier", "id", "updated_at"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.input :field_name, :label => "Field Name", :collection => Vehicle.column_names.sort{|a,b| a[:name] <=> b[:name]} %>
```

Not sure how your data collection is looking like, but i'm fairly sure that should work.

Cheers!

Comment: Got `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`

Comment: Well that means that the column_names array contains arrays, i assumed Hashes. You could edit your Post with the data within column_names and I can probably help you out.